# Rock, Paper, Scissors Update [Error]

Tags: java

So last week I had to create a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors through Java. I had a few issues which I was able to clarify here. Unfortunately I'm in another jam.

So, I am trying to add a feature to be able to play the computer rather than just PvP. I created an array and instructed the program to randomly select through those selections. I then added the logic behind the win/lose using an **if** statement.

Everything looks clean with no errors; until I proceed to integrate my void method into my main method to run the program. I get an error stating

```
C:\Users\AVLG2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\R.P.S.game\src\RPSGame.java:104: error: '.class' expected
        compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);
C:\Users\AVLG2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\R.P.S.game\src\RPSGame.java:104: error: ';' expected
        compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);
C:\Users\AVLG2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\R.P.S.game\src\RPSGame.java:104: error: ';' expected
        compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);
3 errors
```

I double checked to make sure I had all of my ";" and I went back to my win/lose logic and changed `if (P1 == 'P' && cmpChoice == 'R')` to `&& cmpChoice == 1)` and `&& cmpChoice == [0])`

I feel like I'm completely misunderstanding the error. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPSGame {


    //game mode menu
    public static void gameModeSelect (int modeSelect){     
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors 1.0 !\n\nPlease select your game mode:\n ");
        System.out.println("1. Player vs. Computer\n2. Player vs. Player \n ");
    }
    //cvp random choice
    public static void compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice){
        char[] cmp;
        cmp = new char [3];
        cmp[0] = 'R';
        cmp[1] = 'P';
        cmp[2] = 'S';

        cmpChoice = (char) (Math.random()*3);
        System.out.println(cmp[cmpChoice]);
        //game logic CvP  
        if (P1 == 'P' && cmpChoice == 'R'){
            System.out.println("Paper covers rock! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'R' && cmpChoice == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Paper covers rock! Computer wins!");
        }    
        if (P1 == 'R' && cmpChoice == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'S' && cmpChoice == 'R'){
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors! Computer wins!");
        }
        if (P1 == 'S' && cmpChoice == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'P' && cmpChoice == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper! Computer wins!");

        } //game logic for same inputs CvP
        if (P1 == 'P' && cmpChoice == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        } if (P1 == 'R' && cmpChoice == 'R'){
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        } if (P1 == 'S' && cmpChoice == 'S'){
        System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
    }

    //game logic PVP
    public static void PvPwinLoss (char P1, char P2){
    //game logic: paper covers rock, rock breaks paper, scissor cuts paper
        if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'R'){
             System.out.println("Paper covers rock! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Paper covers rock! Player two wins!");
        }    
        if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'R'){
            System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors! Player two wins!");
        }
        if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper! Player one wins!");
        } else if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper! Player two wins!");

        } //game logic for same inputs PvP
        if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'P'){
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        } if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'R'){
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        } if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'S'){
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }

   }
    //game config
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        //player one and two char variables
        char P1;
        char P2;


        //mode selection variable
        int modeSelect = 0;

        //game mode menu selection output
        gameModeSelect (modeSelect);
        modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();

        //error for invalid game mode input
        while ((modeSelect >2) || (modeSelect <1)){
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid game mode");
            gameModeSelect (modeSelect);
            modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        //if game mode input valid:
        if (modeSelect == 1){// under construction
            //game rules
            System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\nGood luck!\n ");
            //request player input
            System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
            P1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Computer has chosen a random move . . .");
            compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);


        } else if (modeSelect == 2){ // player vs. player break down
            //game rules
            System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\nGood luck!\n ");
            //request player input
            System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
            P1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Player two: Enter your move");
            P2 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            PvPwinLoss(P1, P2);//game logic: output - win, lose, or draw
       }       
     }       
}
```

Comment: 1) Your indentations suck. Code is difficult to read. Fix that. --- 2) What did you expect `compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);` to do, as a statement in the middle of the code? If it's supposed to be a method call, why did you include the parameter type? You seem to call method `gameModeSelect` correctly, so why not here? --- 3) Why is `cmpChoice` even a parameter to that method? It looks like it should just be a local variable.

Comment: If I wanted to get rid of some errors, I'd change that call on line 104 into `compRandom(P1)` and change the method declaration of `compRandom` to `public static void compRandom (char P1)`.  But there are other things in your code that are less than ideal.

Comment: @Andreas I'm pretty new to programming, I'll look into fixing my indentations. I didn't realize how difficult it was to read by others. I think I'm going to try removing the array altogether and use ` java.util.Random `

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

1. First read the error message carefully. And fix syntax error that you
   can understand easily:

   `C:\Users\AVLG2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\R.P.S.game\src\RPSGame.java:104: error: ';' expected`

   Here you missed a semi-colon(`;`). Try to fix those first.
2. Format the whole code lines. Use proper indentation, empty lines and naming convention. Those will lead you to navigate through your code easily even for us.

**I think the error that you cannot understand here is:**

```
C:\Users\AVLG2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\R.P.S.game\src\RPSGame.java:104: error: '.class' expected
        compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);
```

`compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice)` is a method that you implemented and it has two parameters. When you calling the method you have to give two argument to match that two parameters.

But what you did is, that **when you calling the method rather than giving values(arguments) you are trying to declare two variables(inside the calling method)**. **It cannot be done**, compiler will confused.

Look at last line:

```
if (modeSelect == 1){// under construction
    //game rules
    System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\nGood luck!\n ");
    //request player input
    System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
    P1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Computer has chosen a random move . . .");
    compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);
}
```

Instead of this `compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);` try passing two values or initialized variables.

Like:

```
compRandom (P1, 'c');
```

this `'c'` to show you. You can put whatever you want.

*It seems to me you copied the method and you forgot to change it.*

Comment: thanks for your help. I still don't see where I'm missing `( ; )` I've looked up and down the code an I feel pretty confident that I didn't miss any. I've made a couple of changes by removing `char cmpChoice` I think I am just going to try to use `java.util.Random` rather than an array

Comment: @Lego91: Look at this lines: `compRandom (char P1, char cmpChoice);`

Comment: In that line you have to pass two values. What you did there is you are trying to initialize two variables. As I said it cannot be done.